# How to stop onMouseOut event after onClick event (ReactJS)?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I need to make a hidden button visible when hovering over an adjacent text. This is being done through `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` events.
But when clicking on the text besides, I need to make the button completely visible and **stop the `onMouseLeave` event**.

So far what I have tried: trying to remove the `onMouseLeave` event using `removeEventListener`.

I know we could do this with the help of a variable like:

```
const mouseOut = (divId) => {
  if (!wasClicked)
      document.getElementById(divId).style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

But since I have way too may different buttons and text, I do not want to use variables either.

```
<div className="step-buttons" onMouseEnter={mouseOver.bind(this, 'feature')}
 onMouseLeave={mouseOut.bind(this, 'feature')} 
 onClick={showButtonOnClick.bind(this, 'feature')}>Test Suite
</div>
```

Is there anything that could help me here?

Any suggestion would be welome,
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Way 1:**
You can mount an eventlistener for leaving in the MouseEnter function and remove it in the onClick eventhandling with refs like so:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.text;
  this.onMouseLeave = this.onMouseLeave.bind(this);
}

onMouseEnter(){
  //apply your styles
  this.text.addEventListener('mouseleave', this.onMouseLeave);
}

onMouseLeave(){
  //remove your styles
}

showButtonOnClick(){
  //remove the eventlistener
  this.text.removeEventListener('mouseleave', this.onMouseLeave);
}

render(){
  return(
    <div ref={(thiscomponent) => {this.text = thiscomponent}} 
      onMouseEnter={this.onMouseEnter.bind(this, 'feature')}
      onClick={this.showButtonOnClick.bind(this, 'feature')}>
      Test Suite
    </div>);
  }
```

The ref ist just a reference for your div, so that you can mount the eventlistener to it.
You have to bind the function in the constructor, as `.bind(this)` will create a new function when you call it, to prevent mounting the eventhandler multiple times.

**Way 2(probably better):**
Another method would be to save the click on the text in the state, and conditionaly change what your onMouseLeave function does based on that:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state={
    clicked: false,
  }
}

onMouseEnter(){
  //apply your styles
}

onMouseLeave(){
  if(!this.state.clicked){
    //remove styles
  }
}

showButtonOnClick(){
  this.setState({clicked: true});
}

render(){
  return(
    <div 
      onMouseEnter={this.onMouseEnter.bind(this)}
      onMouseLeave={this.onMouseLeave.bind(this)}
      onClick={this.showButtonOnClick.bind(this)}>
      Test Suite
    </div>);
  }
```

Comment: can i know what 'c' is used at 'ref={(c) => {this.text = c}}'

Comment: Sorry, got your answer! But the ref is not working for me. Since i'm using redux, how can i do the onMouseLeave event binding?

Comment: As for redux, i have never worked with it, sorry. But i'd guess there must be a way to access your component directly in redux as well, so that you can mount the eventlistener on it.
Maybe [this](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/183) works?

Comment: I've just added another possible way, that might work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use removeEventListener to remove the mouseleave event in your showButtonOnClick function

```
showButtonOnClick(){
    ...your function...
    document.getElementById('step-button').removeEventListener('mouseleave',this.callback());
}

callback(){
   console.log("mouseleave event removed");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are doing this many times, it seems like creating these as components and using its state to store visibility without creating tons of global variables might be worthwhile.